# Spring Batch in clustered environment, high-availability

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, high-availability

Right now I use H2 in-memory database as JobRepostiry for my single node Spring Batch/Boot application.

Now I would like to run Spring Batch application on two nodes in order to increase performance (distribute jobs between these 2 instances) and made the application more failover.

Instead of H2 I'm going to use PostgreSQL and configure both of the applications to use this shared database. Is that enough for Sring Batch in order to start working properly in the cluster and start distributing jobs between cluster nodes or do I need to perform some additional actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you will distribute your jobs across the nodes, you might need to setup a communication middleware (such a JMS or AMQP provider) in addition to a shared job repository.

For example, if you use remote partitioning, your job will be partitioned and each worker can be run on one node. In this case, the job repository must be shared in order for:

- the workers to report their progress to the job repository
- the master to poll the job repository for workers statuses.

If your jobs are completely independent and you don't need feature like restart, you can continue using an in-memory database for each job and launch multiple instances of the same job on different nodes. But even in this case, I would recommend using a production grade job repository instead of an in-memory database. Things can go wrong very quickly in a clustered environment and having a job repository to store the execution status, synchronize executions, restart failed executions, etc is crucial in such an environment.

Comment: My jobs are completely independent but I need to have the possibility to restart them on other nodes in the cluster in case of the node failure. I decided to go with the shared job repository(PostgreSQL) for all of the nodes, shared mounted file system(all nodes will consume and produce data from/to the same folder), and ZooKeeper for running nodes synchronization.

Comment: I'll create ZooKeeper ephemeral node for every task, and during the job restart - I'll check ZooKeeper on the presence of the corresponding ephemeral node for this task and in case of its absence - I'll know that his node is dead and this is the 'zombie' task and can be restarted. What do you think - will it work in that way?

Comment: To be honest, I can't know if this will work. The best answer is give it a try and see how things work in practice.

Comment: @alexanoid I have a similar problem to work on. Did you manage to find any way to run Spring Batch in multi node setup? I have my service running on multiple nodes in k8s. Jobs/tasks need to be able to start from another node in case of node failures. Also, there are many questions like - How to select a owner node for scheduling a task? If you can point to examples it would be great.

Comment: @bluetech I’d recommend you to take a look into Spring Cloud Data Flow and Spring Cloud Task - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/